# ASP.NET MVC jquery dialog _layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have been following this tutorial here: http://evolpin.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/asp-net-mvc-partial-view-and-ajax-real-world-example/ and everything up until the dialog is working fine. However, I am not sure why a dialog isn't opening...

Instead of a dialog opening, it injects the  I've defined in the _Layout of the MVC application, which essentially extends the nav-bar I have at the top of the page. However, I thought because the script is calling a .dialog, it would have the dialog pop open as defined in the ui scripts.

My code for _Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - Spare Part Application</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript">      </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Parts On Hand","Index","PartOnHands")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("VMI","Index","VMIOnHands")</li>
                <li><a href='javascript:showVolumeConstants();'>Set Volume</a></li>
            </ul>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                function showVolumeConstants() {
                    if($('#editVolume').length ==0)
                    {
                        //ajax load
                        $('#volumeScreen').load("@Url.Action("OpenVolume","Home")");
                    } else {
                        // reopen the volume dialog which was previously rendered
                        $("#editVolume").dialog("open");
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </div>
        <div id='volumeScreen'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">

    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - SeaInv</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Here is my partial view:

```
@using System.Web

<div id='editVolume' style="height:150px;">
<h1 style="color:whitesmoke">Edit Volume</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="color:ghostwhite">6 Month Volume:</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBox("volume6month")</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="color:ghostwhite">Quarter Volume:</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBox("volumeQuarter")</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#editVolume").dialog({
        model: true,
        autoOpen: true,
        resizeable: false,
        buttons: [{
            Submit: function () {
                // Edit the volumes entered
                $.post("@Url.Action("EditVolume","Home")",
                    {
                        volume6month: $("volume6month").val(),
                        volumeQuarter: $("volumeQuarter").val()
                    },
                    function (data, status, xhr) {
                        if (data.Success) {
                            $('#editVolume').dialog("close");
                        } else {
                            //Do something
                        }
                    });
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }]
    });
});
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is what my "dialog" code currently does... Not the behavior I want, and with no buttons. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong to add this jqueryUI files or jqueryUI scripts to my code and I'm growing very very frustrated. Can someone please help?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O8Kx.png

Edit: the last thing to mention, I have the partial view rendering in _Layout, but it's controlled by the HomeController. I do not believe this to be an issue though.

Comment: Have you made sure your OpenVolume method on the controller returns a partial view instead of a view? If not it will run through your _ViewStart by default which usually defines the layout as part of the view.

Comment: Hi aph, yes I make sure I do a return PartialView("VolumePartial").
I get the feeling this has something to do with a javascript library not being loaded correctly, but I'm not sure how to check that or why it wouldn't be loading correctly.

Comment: Hi Aph, I have the button and the div used for the dialog as a part of _Layout... would that be part of the problem? Do I need to have the empty div be in a separate page? I want it loaded across all screens though, which is where my issue is. I still think the jquery UI isn't being loaded, and the css for it seems to be connected to that as well. Can anyone provide any advice or help, even if just to start debugging this?